# Laravel migrations: Class "not found"

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, azure

I am deploying a Laravel barebone project to Microsoft Azure, but whenever I try to execute `php artisan migrate` I get the error:

> [2015-06-13 14:34:05] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class '' not found' in D:\home\site\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:328

Stack trace:

```
 #0 {main}
```

What could be the problem? Thank you very much

#### -- edit --

**Migration Class**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->string('surname', 50);
            $table->bigInteger('telephone');
            $table->string('email', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('username', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('password', 50);
            $table->boolean('active')->default(FALSE);
            $table->string('email_confirmation_code', 6);
            $table->enum('notify', ['y', 'n'])->default('y');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->index('username');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**For PSR-4 Auto Loader Users (composer.json):**

Keep the migrations folder inside `classmap` array and do not include it inside psr-4 object under `autoload` head. As migrations' main class Migrator doesn't support namespacing. For example;

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/database/migrations"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\controllers\\": "app/controllers"
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

- First one clears all compiled autoload files.
- Second clears Laravel caches (optional)
- Third builds the autoloader for namespaced classes.
- Fourth optimizes various parts of your Laravel app and builds the autoloader for non-namespaced classes.

From this time onward, you will not have to do this again and any new migrations will work correctly.

Comment: This works perfectly. But could you explain why it is necessary?

Comment: @FelixEve well because migrations don't have namespaces so trying to autoload them through namespace mechanisms (psr-4 etc.) is pointless. The classmap category in composer.json is for such classes. The commands below simply regenerate all the autoload mappings according to the new settings.

Comment: After the first command I ran, whenever I try to run my project, it gives this error ```Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute'``` 
how do I fix it??

Comment: I fixed it !! thanks!! 

**for later concerns!**

if by running the first command, you get the error ```Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute'``` 

this can be fixed by the following steps:

1. !!! remove file /bootstrap/cache/routes.php
2. composer require symfony/routing:v4.2.0
3. php artisan route:cache

step might not complete successfully as the project might be using the another version of symfony route but anyways it will work

Answer (score 82):

Simply make sure your migration filename is the same as your class name.

i.e:

If filename is:

`xxx_151955_create_post_translations_table.php`

Then class should be:

`CreatePostTranslationsTable`

---

If you are using Laravel 9, there is no need for such issue since the migration class are being represented like so:

`return new class extends Migration`

Comment: and remember that xxx is a date with underscores (`_`), I erroneously used hyphens (`-`) and could not figure out what was wrong...

Answer (score 39):

If you get the "Class not found error" when running migrations, please try running this command.

```html
composer dump-autoload
```

then re-issuing the migrate command. See more details in the offical site (#Running Migrations): http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

Comment: Nothing works. Keeps giving me the not found error. I commented the default migration files (users and password_resets) so it would not give me a `"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL error)"` (both `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]` and `[PDOExeption]`. These files are default!!! Why can't I properly use these comands.... also migrate:reset and :rollback give me `Nothing to rollback.` Can you help?

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem a while back. Apparently it is a common problem because in the documentation for Laravel, it even suggests it: http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

Basically all you have to do is refresh some composer files. Simply run:

`composer dump-autoload`

This will refresh composer autoload files and then you can run your normal migration and it should work! Very best.

Answer (score 9):

i also run in the same problem.

The solution for me was to delete the migration file, AND delete the record from the "migrations" table in the database.

After that, I ran

> composer dump-autoload

and was finally able to reset/rollback migrations.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's late to answer this question but maybe this will help someone.

If you changed the migration file name, be sure about its inner class name.

For example, If I change a migration name from `2018_06_10_079999_create_admins_table.php` to `2018_06_10_079999_create_managers_table.php` so its inner class name must change from `CreateAdminsTable` to `CreateManagerTable` too.

Answer (score 6):

I deleted one of the migration file. faced the same problem, while `php artisan migrate:rollback`

Then I tried `composer dump-autoload`. Again the same turned up.

I restored the deleted file and tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan migrate:rollback`. It works.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the problem was that I had named my migration 2017_12_15_012645_create_modules_problems.php, with the class name of CreateModulesProblemsTable. As soon as I added _table to the filename, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

i face this problem when i rename migrations to :

0_create_activities_table.php

i solve it when i rename it to:

2019_10_01_0_create_activities_table.php

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure your migrations filename matches with migration class name**

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

If name of migration is:

*2020_10_31_161839_create_notifications_table*

Then the class name should be:

*CreateNotificationsTable*

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation (class not found error) after moving a Laravel 5.2 dev project to production.  The production server was looking for class "project" but the controller name was Project.php.  Once I renamed the file to project.php it was good to go.

Answer (score 2):

**simply delete the row at your database on table `migrations`** and that will fix the problem. It will not show anymore when you do migrations

other way is to simply create the file it depends of what u want, in my case I wanted to get rid of this migration. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same class not found error when trying to migrate my project. Sometimes it is the simple things that get you. In my case, I noticed that my class name was not correct in my migration file due to me making a rename change early on and not carrying that change throughout.

After correcting the class name I performed a composer dump-autoload and my issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had foolishly put:

```
namespace database\migrations;
```

Inside my migration create_users_table.php 
[2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php]

I was getting a similar error - Class 'CreateUsersTable' not found.

Removing this line at the top solved this error.