# Want to add column but migration class is not found even It exists

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, migration, phpstorm

I am learning Laravel.

Here is my migration file code.

```
class CreatePostTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); // i want to add this column after adding this line i runs the command refresh but it shows below errors.
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('post');
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem that whenever I run this command in terminal in PhpStorm:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

it shows following errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AddIsAdminColumnToPostTable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php on line 335
>
> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'AddIsAdminColumnToPostTable' not found

I tried `composer dump-autoload` in terminal [solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819934/laravel-migrations-class-not-found) but it's not working. I also used `rollback` command but still having issue.

How can make `refresh` this?

Comment: Have you tried running it from console/terminal? If it has the same results (does not work) then this issue has nothing to do with PhpStorm.

Comment: Yes running from terminal.. then what is the problem?

Comment: @LazyOne Then what i have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: In such case it's some sort of misconfiguration or Laravel-related issue -- I cannot help in this regard as I have no idea about your project.

Comment: @LazyOne ok Thanks, I just solved my problem i delete the migration file, and runs the command again the create command from terminal and then i runs the refresh command it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Artisan looks for migrations based on the file name. If you want it to be called something else: rollback, delete the migration, make a new migration. Or, change the file name to exactly match the class name.

For you, try changing

```
class CreatePostTable extends Migration
```

to

```
class AddIsAdminColumnToPostTable extends Migration
```

Comment: but i have an other class which have name `AddIsAdminColumnToPostTable` i just show this class because i wants to add column in post table.