# Laravel package migration class can not find sibling class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a Laravel package.

This is my folder structure:

```
- host => (a laravel app to test the package)
   - WebSite
       - packages
           - Company
               - FirstPackage
                   - database
                       - migrations
                   - src
                       - Models
                       - Http
                           - Controllers
```

Inside `migrations` folder I have two migration classes:

`2021-06-04-create-customers-table`
`2021-06-04-add-name-to-customers`

Inside `CreateCustomersTable` class I have a constant called `TABLE_NAME`.

Inside `AddNameToCustomers` class I want to reuse that constant, and I simply use it like `CreateCustomersTable::TABLE_NAME`.

My IDE which is VS Code does not complain. But when I run `php artisan migration`, I get this error:

> Class 'CreateCustomersTable' not found
> at packages/Company/FirstPackage/database/migrations/2021-06-04-add-name-to-customers.php:line_number

Based on [Laravel migrations: Class "not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819934/laravel-migrations-class-not-found), I made sure class names match file names, and I also tried to map classes in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/migrations"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Company\\FirstPackage\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

But none of these values worked for me:

`database/migrations`
`app/database/migrations`
`Company/FirstPackage/database/migrations`

So I have two questions.

First: How can I fix this?

Second and more important: How should I debug **class not found** bugs?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `composer dumpautoload` first, if it doesn't help follow below steps:)

First way: use a flag when executing migration commands.
This is inconvenient, but if you really need it, you can try:

`php artisan migrate --path=/path/to/your/dir/with/migrations`

Second way: you can add the paths that your migrations are in to your AppServiceProvider using `$this->loadMigrationsFrom($paths);`

> How should I debug class not found bugs?

- Check file name and class name;
- Check the path where the class is located;
- Run `composer dumpautoload` it can help you with warning messages like this

`Class App\Namespace\To\Class\ClassName located in ./app/directory/to/class/ClassName.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`;

- And finally you can check `vendor/composer/autoload_*` files to find your mistakes.