# Laravel Migration Class not Found

Tags: php, laravel

When I run `php artisan migrate` to migrate my database

I get the following error:

```
In Migrator.php line 448:

  Class 'AddNewStatusFlagsToUsersTable' not found
```

This is my code for my migration.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddNewStatusFlagsToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('decline_plg')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('unresponsive')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('filing_directly_to_amazon')->default(false);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('decline_plg');
            $table->dropColumn('unresponsive');
            $table->dropColumn('filing_directly_to_amazon');
        });
    }
}
```

Filename `2022_10_05_184432_add_new_status_flags_to_users_table.php`

I've run this commands:

`php artisan clear-compiled`

`php artisan optimize:clear`

`composer dump-autoload`

`php artisan optimize`

But still nothing works.

How to solve this laravel migration?

Answer (score 0):

change `class AddNewStatusFlagsToUsersTable extend Migration` to `return new class extends migration` to use Anonymous Migrations:

```
 <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    return new class extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->boolean('decline_plg')->default(false);
                $table->boolean('unresponsive')->default(false);
                $table->boolean('filing_directly_to_amazon')->default(false);
            });
        }
    
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('decline_plg');
                $table->dropColumn('unresponsive');
                $table->dropColumn('filing_directly_to_amazon');
            });
        }
    }
```

- optional for laravel 8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#anonymous-migrations
- the standard way in laravel 10: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#migration-structure

Comment: I'm using laravel 5. Tried this but still nothing works.. I don't know why its giving me this error.

Comment: Is it failing when dropping tables? If so wipe your database tables with php artisan db:wipe then run migrations

Comment: Also check out this post : https://stackoverflow.com/q/30819934/20058203

Comment: AJZack indeed up renaming to `022_10_05_184432_add_new_status_flags_to_users_table2.php` instead I added `2` because I have two same name migrations but with different dates. Don't know why but it seems to work now.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano delete the one that you don't need, happy coding.